# How do I replace instructions within a PE file using Python?

Tags: python, assembly, disassembly, portable-executable, malware

I'd like to replace assembly instructions within the code (.text) section of a PE image with semantically equivalent instructions that are of the same length. An example would be replacing an "add 5" with a "sub -5", though certainly I have much more elaborate plans than this.

I've found that LIEF is great for working with higher-level features in a PE file and can give you a dump of the code section data. The same seems to apply for the pefile library. They don't seem to be great tools for manipulating individual instructions though, unless I'm missing something.

The goal would be to perform some initial disassembly and looping through instructions in order to locate interesting or desirable instructions (e.g., the add instruction from above). Then I'd prefer to not have to figure out all of the opcodes and generate bytes by hand. If possible, I'd be looking for something more developer-friendly that computes it for you (E.g., this.intr = 'add' and this.op1 = '5'). Ideally it wouldn't try to re-assemble the entire section after the change is made... this could cause other differences to occur, and my use case requires that this individual instruction be the only change present from a bit-level perspective. Again, the idea is that I'd only be selecting semantically equivalent instructions whose lengths are equal, which is what would allow this scenario to occur without re-assembling from scratch.

How can I do something like this using Python?

Comment: This question might fall under section 4 of this [help/on-topic] page - "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Maybe try reworking the question to be more on-topic if nobody's answering.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that now. I appreciate the heads up.

Comment: Do remember that PE files have a checksum.  If the publisher has signed the file, as many now do, your tampering will invalidate the signature.